# Get Correct Texture from Object

Tags: texturing

So the problem is that the sword has a texture that works for what I need in blender, but I can't find out how to get the texture.

[image]

All I have is a drawing of one side of the sword, but in blender it is applied to both sides. **I need to convert how it is displayed in blender into a texture.**

[image]

Comment: So you want to put a different texture on the other side of the sword?

Comment: Or do you want to mirror the same texture on both sides of the sword?

Comment: The texture is on both sides of the sword already, but I'm trying to export a texture that actually fits the object. Like I need to be able to import that object into another program and have a working texture for it as a png/jpg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bake the texture:

Create a second UV map without overlapping. Create new image texture (press *New* in the *UV / Image Editor* view) and add it to your material node setup. Connect the new UV map to this texture vector slot using the *Input / UV Map* node, or in older versions of blender the *Input / Attribute* node. Select the new texture, so it becomes the active texture. Now you can bake texture to the second map, and then save it from the *UV / Image Editor* view.

[image: Material node setup for Cycles]

Answer (score 0):

1. Tab into Object Mode and keep your model selected.
2. In the Properties Window, go to the Texture Panel and select the texture slot (in my picture there are three textures for diffuse, normal and specularity, with the diffuse texture selected)
3. Scroll down to the image panel and look up the texture name in the "Source" field.

[image]