# Material diffuse colour bake into texture

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

So I am very new to blender but I have been using it to create basic models for my game. Up until now I have been painting images but my friends are using material diffuse colours instead so they can create low poly design models. My game engine only supports textures so it would be great if the diffuse colours for the model could be baked into a texture. If there is a script that can do this or a function in blender itself to do this that would be great to know. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, you can find answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60511/get-correct-texture-from-object/60521#60521

Comment: You can do this within blender. There are tons of comprehensible beginner tutorials about texturing objects in Blender including UV unwrapping allover the internet. They do a better job than we could do on BlenderSE.